# Usage of jacococli.jar with multiple classfiles

Tags: jacoco

As in most cases my class files are at 2 locations inside tomcat at, `lib` and `classes`. Now once `.exec` file is created I need to pull a report referencing both the locations `classes` and a few jars in `lib`, for this I am using the below command

```
java -jar jacococli.jar report /local/jacoco.exec --html /jacocoReport/html --name MergeCode --classfiles /tomcat/webapps/<app>/WEB-INF/lib/new.jar /tomcat/webapps/<app>/WEB-INF/classes
```

but it is throwing error, and from the error it looks like it is considering the second location/jar from `--classfiles` option as an exec file.

```
[INFO] Loading execution data file /local/jacoco.exec.
[INFO] Loading execution data file /tomcat/webapps/<app>/WEB-INF/classes.
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tomcat/webapps/<app>/WEB-INF/classes (Is a directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at org.jacoco.cli.internal.core.tools.ExecFileLoader.load(ExecFileLoader.java:71)
at org.jacoco.cli.internal.commands.Report.loadExecutionData(Report.java:98)
at org.jacoco.cli.internal.commands.Report.execute(Report.java:82)
at org.jacoco.cli.internal.Main.execute(Main.java:89)
at org.jacoco.cli.internal.Main.main(Main.java:104)
```

I have tried moving classes before the jar file, the exception is different

```
[INFO] Loading execution data file /local/jacoco.exec.
[INFO] Loading execution data file /tomcat/webapps/<app>/WEB-INF/lib/new.jar.
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Invalid execution data file.
at org.jacoco.cli.internal.core.data.ExecutionDataReader.read(ExecutionDataReader.java:89)
at org.jacoco.cli.internal.core.tools.ExecFileLoader.load(ExecFileLoader.java:59)
at org.jacoco.cli.internal.core.tools.ExecFileLoader.load(ExecFileLoader.java:73)
at org.jacoco.cli.internal.commands.Report.loadExecutionData(Report.java:98)
at org.jacoco.cli.internal.commands.Report.execute(Report.java:82)
at org.jacoco.cli.internal.Main.execute(Main.java:89)
at org.jacoco.cli.internal.Main.main(Main.java:104)
```

for

```
java -jar jacococli.jar classinfo /tomcat/webapps/<app>/WEB-INF/lib/new.jar /tomcat/webapps/<app>/WEB-INF/classes /tomcat/webapps/<app>/WEB-INF/lib/new1.jar
```

multiple files work fine all classes in the `classes` folder and set of jar files in `lib` folder are listed,

Documentation at http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/cli.html states that `--classfiles` for report can have multiple files but does not state example or delimiter. I tried with comma, semicolon but it does not work ' '[space] works with classinfo so I am assuming it should work with report also.

Googling also did not result in any examples for jacococli.jar.

Comment: Try `java -jar jacococli.jar report /local/jacoco.exec --html /jacocoReport/html --name MergeCode --classfiles /tomcat/webapps/<app>/WEB-INF/lib/new.jar --classfiles /tomcat/webapps/<app>/WEB-INF/classes`. Note that prefix `--classfiles` is specified twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Documentation at http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/cli.html states that --classfiles for report can have multiple files

This is wrong - documentation at http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/cli.html actually states that

> Some parameters can be specified multiple times to provide multiple values.

And

```
--classfiles <path>
```

can be specified multiple times literally, i.e.

```
--classfiles path1 --classfiles path2
```

When you omit prefix `--classfiles`, then it is interpreted as

```
<execfiles>
```

giving exceptions

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tomcat/webapps/<app>/WEB-INF/classes (Is a directory)
> at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
> at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
> at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
> at org.jacoco.cli.internal.core.tools.ExecFileLoader.load(ExecFileLoader.java:71)
> ```

and

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Invalid execution data file.
> at org.jacoco.cli.internal.core.data.ExecutionDataReader.read(ExecutionDataReader.java:89)
> at org.jacoco.cli.internal.core.tools.ExecFileLoader.load(ExecFileLoader.java:59)
> ```

as expected - as in one case it is not a file and in another case it is not valid exec file.

> ' '[space] works with classinfo so I am assuming it should work with report also

`report` and `classinfo` are two different commands and have different arguments with all the consequences. Space works with `classinfo` command, because it allows multiple specifications of

```
<classlocations>
```

note absence of need to specify prefix in comparison to `report` command.

Comment: is it possible to use wildcards to get multiple classfiles? i.e. `--classfiles application/**/*.class`  When I try this I get `Invalid execution data file`